Separation to lib and logic in android studio application (kotlin)
I created this fully working dotsandboxes game in Android Studio mainly in a file called dotsandboxesview that contains lots of functions for playing the game drawing the line and grid, etc. I then needed to move this code to my lib and logic files i think and make them all work together. This is where I'm getting stuck on what to do as when I try moving it around it doesn't seem to work. I'm going to include some screenshots for reference. enter image description here
I've tried asking AI to separate the file into the other files shown but it never seems to work and I always have to change the Gradle and then that creates even more errors. Here is one of the errors I got, but of course, the errors change every time I try to move the code. This came up when I run the testing:enter image description here
